How to convert CRLF on an empty line to \n without affecting other CRLF code elsewhere
I am writing a family history mini novel and have been working on it on a different PC.
I used an old version of UltraEdit for my word processor. But it was not very compatible with Windows after XP. I read a post somewhere on getting it to work on Windows 7 that worked, and that survived a data transfer to my Windows 10 laptop. Then one day it crashed and I couldn't fix it. So a lot of my friends told me to try Notepad++, claiming it to be better than UltraEdit 13. I tried to work on it in Notepad++, but the formatting was broken. Instead of my paragraphs that were all on one line and wrapped at the edge of the screen automatically, then a blank line between them, like I wrote it, it was all broken up. I turned on "Show Symbols" and instead one one CRLF at the end of each paragraph line, followed by a CRLF for the empty line, there were multiple CRLFs in it. To the tune about 200% more than I wanted.
I've tried to type some text here to show the way it looks in Notepad++, but this message board fixes it so it looks like it should. So I can't show you what it looks like. However, I found this on here somewhere, do a RegEx search\replace for \R(?!\R) and that fixes the lines in the paragraphs. However, I wanted that empty line between paragraphs, because I add them in without thinking about it. So now that there is only one CRLF per paragraph, is there a RegEx search\replace to add a \n at the end of each line with text on it so that line is created between paragraphs already written? This is driving me crazy. But I can't afford to update UltraEdit. and I probably wouldn't like the new version anyway...

Can you show an example of what you want but put /r or /n/r in the various places just to demonstrate? I know Notepad++ has a tool to change in-bulk between CRLF, LF and CR, but I'm not sure if you want something more selective. What exact conditions do you want to apply?

Why don't you use Word or LibreOffice Document Writer (it's free) instead of a text editor?

What do you have in the Notepad++ Encoding menu ?

As I said, the RegEx I mentioned fixes the lines in the paragraphs, but doing that also removes the line between paragraphs and I was trying to find a way to put it back, without messing with the remaining CRLF. And I just figured it out. First I do the RegEx search\replace to replace \R(?!\R) with Nothing, then I do another and change \r to \r\n. That worked! Now I can get on with it and write the rest of this for my daughter. Thanks for reminding me of what I was forgetting, Mokubai! (Don't let anyone fool you, getting old is not always a walk in the park.)

Not sure I well understand, you want to remove linebreaks only if there are not preceeded nor followed by another linebreak.

This does the job:

Ctrl+H
Find what: (\R\R)\R*|\R
Replace with: $1
SELECT Regular expression
Replace all

Explanation:
(\R\R)      # 2 linebreaks (i.e. paragraphs spacing)
\R*         # 0 or more linebreaks, optional
|           # OR
\R          # a single linebreak

Replacement:
$1          # content of group 1, 2 linebreaks


Easy to fix in Notepad++:

Press CtrlH for the Search/Replace dialog.



Set Search Mode to Extended.

Enter \r\n\r\n in Find what:, i.e., a brace of CR and LF characters.

Enter \r\n\ in Replace with:.

Click Replace All.
Each time that button is clicked, the number of duplicated CR/LF pairs is reduced throughout the whole document. This creates a single line break at the end of each paragraph. Switch the above arguments to double line spacing.


If you want consistent double line spacing

Change all to single line spacing, as shown above.
Then search for  all \r\n and replace with \r\n\r\n, once.

Even more advanced search features are available using Regular expression.

As far as I understand the question, they want to have an empty line between each paragraph.

@Toto, that is not my understanding of the question: "instead one one CRLF at the end of each paragraph line, followed by a CRLF for the empty line, there were multiple CRLFs in it. To the tune about 200% more than I wanted."

Correct. I have made a note of your suggestion as well, and put it with the other notes I have on Notepad++. Thanks! If I could figure out the kudos thing, you both would get some from me.

@AxelSlingerland: What, who is correct?

Technically you both were, Toto. You were correct that I do want an empty line between each paragraph. However, DrMoishe Pippik was also correct, as he quoted me directly. Combine that with the title, and everything else I typed really wasn't necessary. But as the evil witch I had for a 4th grade teacher was right... I'm "wordy". It's taking me awhile, but I'm learning Notepad++. But I still wish I could get UltraEdit 13 to work, as I used it for years and I was used to it. But if I fixed today I would probably think Notepad++ was better the moment I tried to do anything. :)
